# RSpec expectation on stub fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec3, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Here's the call I would like to test expectations for:

```
UserMailer.invoice_paid(user, invoice).deliver_later
```

Rails 5 ActionMailer behaviour in `:test` mode seems to return nil on every method of an ApplicationMailer class. This should be fine since I can just stub it like so:

```
invoice_paid_dbl = double(ActionMailer::MessageDelivery)
allow(UserMailer).to receive(:invoice_paid).and_return(invoice_paid_dbl)
```

This expectation fails:

```
expect(UserMailer).to receive(:invoice_paid).once
```

While this one passes:

```
expect(invoice_paid_dbl).to receive(:deliver_later).once
```

Shouldn't that be impossible? I thought maybe the method chain was confusing RSpec, but splitting up the line into this has no effect:

```
mail = UserMailer.invoice_paid(user, invoice)
mail.deliver_later
```

Adding `.with(any_args)` to the stub and expectation also has no effect (since that's the default anyways). The failure is expected: 1 time with any arguments, received: 0 times with any arguments.

Comment: how you have stubbed the method?

Answer (score 0):

Not getting how you have stubbed methods, but think that following will work for you

You are trying to stub chain of methods so need to use `stub_chain` instead of `stub`

```
UserMailer.stub_chain(:invoice_paid, :deliver_later).and_return(:invoice_paid_dbl)
```

I hope this will work and solve you problem. For more details please check [docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-0/docs/stubs/stub-a-chain-of-methods)

Comment: The `allow(...).to_receive and_return(...)` line is a stub method. Unfortunately your example still doesn't allow `expect(UserMailer).to receive(:invoice_paid)` to pass, and it's deprecated.

Comment: Then please share your test expectation blocks

Comment: Thanks for your help here but it was just a dumb mistake. I already had that expectation met earlier in the block. It was the second expectation of that type which wasn't being met. My bad!

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave the question up in case it helps others, but this was actually the result of a silly mistake. I had `expect(UserMailer).to receive(:invoice_paid)` earlier in the `it` block, and it was passing. It was the second expectation of that type which was failing. Oops.